# How to display wishlist icon only if wishlist is enabled by admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, wishlist

How to display wishlist icon only if wishlist is enabled by admin

Comment: If answer below does not help, please post your template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Magento 1 you can add this to your template:

> app\design\frontend\THEME\PACKAGE\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

```
<?php if($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()): ?>
// your icon code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks..I also want count for the wish list item..How to achieve this??

Comment: Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038840/display-current-users-number-of-wishlist-items-in-top-links-on-shared-wishli

Comment: <?php $moduleName = 'wishlist';
          $cartCount = Mage::helper('wishlist/wishlist')->getCart()->getSummaryQty();?>

            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
         <a class="trigger-link-wish-list" href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>wishlist/">
    <span class="trigger-icon icon-heart"></span>
        <?php if ($cartCount > 0): ?>
            <span class="cart-counter">
                <?php echo $cartCount; ?>
            </span>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-counter cart-counter--zero">0</span>
*Please help me in this code.*

Comment: Can please open a new question ... code is hard to read in comments.